# Загрузка файла на хост

Tags: уязвимости, php, mysql

Вопрос по безопасности. На сайте есть форма, которая делает выборку из MYSQL, при это нет никакой защиты от sql-инъекции. Можно но ли используя эту ошибку залить на сайт файл?

Answer (score 1):

Только в том случае если знаете путь куда лить (нужен абсолютный), есть права на работу с файлами у mysql пользователя с которым работает скрипт и mq на сервере off.

Comment: Путь есть куда лить, папка доступна для записи, magic quotes off, про права не могу сказать, думаю что они есть. Как сформировать запрос правильно?

Comment: Вам помочь взломать сайт? Боюсь это не по адресу ...

Comment: Смотрите справку про INTO OUTFILE, и в зависимости от запроса в скрипте добавляйте свой.

PS и да, ломать чужие сайны плохо и аморально, не говоря уже о том что найдут ноги выдернут :D

Comment: OUTFILE и LOAD_FILE к сожалению не применимы. Какие еще есть варианты?